# How to access AngularJS data returned as complex object (Pubnub)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I am using a 3rd party library (Pubnub) that has `$pubnubChannel` method to load data in a controller so you can display updates easily.

In the controller you use it like this:

`$scope.messages = $pubnubChannel(myChannel,{ autoload: 2 });`

And then in the view `$scope.messages` will properly display 2 messages. So far, so good.

But I want to directly access the data in the controller like this:

`var myMessage =  $scope.messages[0].content` but I can't figure out how to get the actual data.

Assume the data looks like this:

```
{ 
content:"Hi"
date:"2017-05-13T12:12:14.048Z"
id:"xyz123"
sender_guid:"12345678" 
}
```

If I run this:

`console.log($scope.messages)` I see a complex object:

```
> 0: Object
> 1: Object
> $$getPrototypeMethods:function ()
> $$getPublicMethods:function ()
> $$newMessage:function ()
> $channel:function()
etc
etc
```

All the functions from the $pubnubChannel method are shown in the output.

The data that I want is in the `Object` entries. I tried to get it like this:

```
var myMessage =  $scope.messages[0].content
```

but this does not return anything. How to I get to the data objects?

Answer (score 1):

Your messages are probably stored in **$messages**.

`var myMessage = $scope.messages.$messages[0].content`

Found it in source code here: https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-angular/blob/master/src/pubnub_channel.js

In line 47 you can see that `this.$messages = [];` part of the $pubnubChannel factory.